# Maven yuicompressor-plugin generates minified js encoded in ANSI

Tags: maven, encoding, yui-compressor

I'm trying to minify a group of js files with maven's yuicompressor-plugin. One of this files has to be encoded in UTF-8 because it has special characters:

```
String.prototype.removeTicks = function (/*thisArg */) {
    var __r = 
    {
        'À':'A','Á':'A','Â':'A','Ã':'A','Ä':'A','Å':'A','Æ':'E',
        'È':'E','É':'E','Ê':'E','Ë':'E',
        'Ì':'I','Í':'I','Î':'I',
        'Ò':'O','Ó':'O','Ô':'O','Ö':'O',
        'Ù':'U','Ú':'U','Û':'U','Ü':'U',
        'N':'N'
    };

    return this.replace(/[ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÈÉÊËÌÍÎÒÓÔÖÙÚÛÜÑ]/gi, function(m)
    {
        var ret = __r[m.toUpperCase()];

        if (ret && m === m.toLowerCase())
            ret = ret.toLowerCase();

        return ret;
    });
};
```

But, when I run the compressor the output file is encoded in ANSI and all special characters are broken. I tried to configure the charset encoding in the plugin configuration and change all files to UTF-8, but none of this work. Here is the pom extract:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>yuicompressor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>compress</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <nosuffix>true</nosuffix>
        <nocompress>true</nocompress>
        <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/../../public</sourceDirectory>
        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target</outputDirectory>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <aggregations>
            <aggregation>
                <removeIncluded>true</removeIncluded>
                <output>${basedir}/target/${project.build.finalName}/js/custom.js</output>
                <inputDir>${basedir}/target/js</inputDir>
                <includes>
                    <include>util/string/string.js</include>
                    <include>...</include>                                
                </includes>
            </aggregation>
        </aggregations>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Anyone ever had this problem and solved it?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you placed the correct charset in  tag for the script you are injecting. This might work.

```
<script src="foo.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```